# How to optimize the small matrix multiplication ((5,5) x (5,25)) in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

I have a function which conduct 3 small matrix mulitplications ((5,5) x (5,25)). But in a HPC program which will call seveal billion times of this function. How could I speed up this function to make my HPC program faster?  The function is defined in this way:

```
function mxm(A,B1,B2,B3):
```

where A is of shape(5,5), B1-3 are of the shape(5,25), and the output matrix C1-3 are

```
C1 = A * B1; C2 = A * B2; C3 = A * B3;
```

I have an example by using Eigen here:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "test.hpp"

int main(){
    Eigen::Array<float,5,5,1> A;
    Eigen::Array<float,5,25,1> B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3,D1,D2,D3;

    A.setRandom(); B1.setRandom(); 
    B2.setRandom(); B3.setRandom();

    clock_t tic,toc;
    const int nn = 500000;

    tic = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < nn; i ++){
        mxm5_eigen(A.data(),B1.data(),B2.data(),B3.data(),C1.data(),
            C2.data(),C3.data());
    }
    toc = clock();
    std::cout << "Eigen time " << (double)(toc-tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n"; 

    tic = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < nn; i ++){
        mxm5(A.data(),B1.data(),B2.data(),B3.data(),D1.data(),
            D2.data(),D3.data());
    }
    toc = clock();
    std::cout << "unrolled loop time " << (double)(toc-tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";
}
```

test.hpp

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

void inline mxm5_eigen(const float *__restrict Ain,const float *__restrict B1in,
          const float *__restrict B2in,const float *__restrict B3in,
          float *__restrict C1in,float *__restrict C2in,float *__restrict C3in)
{
    const int n1 = 5, n3 = 25;
    Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<float,5,5,1>> A(Ain);
    Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<float,5,25,1>> B1(B1in),B2(B2in),B3(B3in);
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float,5,25,1>> C1(C1in),C2(C2in),C3(C3in);

    C1.noalias() = A * B1;
    C2.noalias() = A * B2;
    C3.noalias() = A * B3;
}

// c[i,j] = sum_k A[i,k] * B[k,j]
void inline mxm5(const float *__restrict A,const float *__restrict B1,
          const float *__restrict B2,const float *__restrict B3,
          float *__restrict C1,float *__restrict C2,float *__restrict C3)
{
    const int  n1 = 5, n3 = 25;
    for(int i = 0; i < n1; i ++){
        #pragma GCC ivdep
        for(int j = 0; j < n3; j ++){
            int idx = i * n3 + j;
            C1[idx] = A[i * n1 + 0] * B1[0 * n3 + j] + 
                      A[i * n1 + 1] * B1[1 * n3 + j] +
                      A[i * n1 + 2] * B1[2 * n3 + j] +
                      A[i * n1 + 3] * B1[3 * n3 + j] +
                      A[i * n1 + 4] * B1[4 * n3 + j];

            C2[idx] = A[i * n1 + 0] * B2[0 * n3 + j] + 
                      A[i * n1 + 1] * B2[1 * n3 + j] +
                      A[i * n1 + 2] * B2[2 * n3 + j] +
                      A[i * n1 + 3] * B2[3 * n3 + j] +
                      A[i * n1 + 4] * B2[4 * n3 + j];

            C3[idx] = A[i * n1 + 0] * B3[0 * n3 + j] + 
                      A[i * n1 + 1] * B3[1 * n3 + j] +
                      A[i * n1 + 2] * B3[2 * n3 + j] +
                      A[i * n1 + 3] * B3[3 * n3 + j] +
                      A[i * n1 + 4] * B3[4 * n3 + j];                   
        }
    }
}
```

And I compile it by using `g++ main.cpp -O3 -march=native -ffast-math -I/path/to/eigen/`
The result computational time is :

```
Eigen time 0.078125                                                                                                     unrolled loop time 0.03125
```

It seems the computation time from unrolled loop is much faster than Eigen. I want to know if there are any more optimized methods to do this computation.

Comment: Try keeping C1 C2 C3 transposed to improve cache locality.